# RangeAttribute Data Annotation Not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC2 application in which I have a `User` class with a property named `SecurityQuestionID` as follows:

```
public class User
{
    [RangeAttribute(1, 5, ErrorMessage = "Security Question is required")]
    [DisplayName("Security Question")]
    public virtual int SecurityQuestionID { get; set; }
}
```

The `SecurityQuestionID` field gets populated from a dropdown in the view as follows:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityQuestionID)%>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SecurityQuestionID, ViewData["securityQuestions"] as SelectList,"Choose a Question",null) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityQuestionID)%>
```

The controller sends the security questions to the view by using view data as follows:

```
ViewData["securityQuestions"] = new SelectList(_securityQuestionService.GetAll(), "SecurityQuestionID", "Question");
```

If I don't select a question from the dropdown and hit the submit button, then "`The Security Question field is required.`" message is displayed instead of "`Security Question is required`". Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the integer is not nullable, then it is required by default. So the range validation isn't failing but Required validation is failing.
You may want to specify a separate error message for when it is required by adding a required attribute.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Security Question is required")]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably throwing that error because it is a required field.  See http://forums.asp.net/p/1391688/2977493.aspx.  This is consistent with the fact that the field in question is defined as an `int`, and not an `int?`, so it cannot assume a `null` value.

In other words, it's not hitting your range validator.